# UnauthorizedAccessException When trying get access rules using DirectorySecurity library

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I am trying to get a particular folder write access for users using a method that gets access rules and checks wheather the logged in user has write access for that folder. But when trying to do this I am getting an error stating UnauthorizedException.I have checked the folder access and everything looks good.I Below is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

```
 private bool AccessPackerPlanTemplate()
        {
            bool result = true;
            UserBUList userBUList = new UserBUList();

            try
            {
                string PackerPlanTemplate = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PackerPlanTemplate"];

                userBUList.UserName = (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Name.Split('\\')[1].ToString();
                string path = PackerPlanTemplate;
                string NtAccountName = userBUList.UserName;

                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);         //I AM GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE        
                System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

                //Go through the rules returned from the DirectorySecurity
                foreach (System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
                {
                    //If we find one that matches the identity we are looking for
                    if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(NtAccountName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //Cast to a FileSystemAccessRule to check for access rights
                        if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData) > 0)
                        {
                            result = true ;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Does somebody has any suggestion regarding Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have the permissions to see the access lists? Is the directory Read only?

Comment: @Matt Clark : I have checked the access and the directory is writable. Also. I am trying with my account and it has full access on the directory and the file.

Comment: Does that happen also when you execute the program as an administrator?